# How to control more than one (generated via php and db) checkbox in jquery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, mousedown

I have in my html page a list of checkboxes

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="example1" value="1">
 <input type="checkbox" id="example2" value="2">
```

generated via php, according to the content of a database table, containing the details of the elements to be displayed.
I don't know how much checkboxes i will have at any moment in the page, for the number can change according to the database content.

Now, in order to reply to the hit of a checkbox i was thinking to use

```
 $('#example').mousedown(function() {   
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        this.checked = confirm("Are you sure?");
        $(this).trigger("change");
    }
 });
```

but this way means to know the name/id of the checkbox which i don't know, cause it is generated... 
So, how i can generate my checkbox and control which was hitten via jquery?

Comment: You could loop on the checkboxes controls instead of hitting them with the ID. Or give them a class and select all elements with that class...

Comment: giving them a class instead of an id seems to work, but how do i get the value of the hitten checkbox?

Comment: cfr my answer... and don't look at my remark on looping through the item, i didn't realize you wanted to keep the "checked" event and wanted to treat all checkboxes upon submitting the form or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving a class to your checkboxes :

```
<input type="checkbox" class="cls1" id="example1" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" class="cls1" id="example2" value="2">
```

Then, when binding the `mousedown` event, instead of selecting them by their id, select them with that class :

```
 $('.cls1').mousedown(function() {   
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        this.checked = confirm("Are you sure?");
        $(this).trigger("change");
    }
 });
```

This is to stay as close as possible from your original code, which may not be the best. Without a broader view on it it's hard to tell. Note that in the case you're adding dynamically the checkboxes clientside (which is not the case I presume cause you talk about generating it with PhP) you would need a different selector in order to use what is called [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)